# Prevent Kestrel from logging errors that are handled in ExceptionFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, kestrel

I use an exception filter to log exceptions in my ASP.NET Core app like this:

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var resource = $"{request?.Method}: {request?.Path}{request?.QueryString}";

    var logger = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<ILogger<ExceptionFilter>>();
    logger.LogError(0, context.Exception, $"Error in SB.API - {resource}");           
}
```

This works fine, but Kestrel also logs this event giving me a duplicate entry.

How can I prevent this error from propagating further when I have logged it manually like this?

I do not want to completely turn it off, because then I might miss errors that occur in other parts of the pipeline.

Comment: Try to check `Log filtering` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `context.ExceptionHandled = true;` and then Kestrel will know you took care of it and will not log it.